# Get a file from IVirtualImageProvider

Tags: imageresizer

I have a custom plugin for serving images trought LDAP `IPlugin`
 and `IVirtualImageProvider` now im doing a task of importing users from LDAP to our own system and as such i need to import those images, i was wondering if there is any way of using the plugin i previously created to import those images, perhaps something in the like of

```
ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob("http://host/ad/A68986", "~/uploads/<guid>.<ext>", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(
              "width=2000;height=2000;format=jpg;mode=max"));
```

But the first parameter (source) would be "resolved" by my LDAP plugin, ImageResizer API

**Edit:** I figured out this is possible since source can be a IVirtualFile, that implies that i know in advance which one to create (for my case my own ldap) it would be nice to pass the url and somehow get the correct IVirtualFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ImageJob resolves any 'app-relative virtual paths' using installed IVirtualImageProviders. Such paths must begin with "~/", and match the path prefix and syntax you've designed, of course.

In your case, this might look like

```
var i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob("~/ad/A68986", "~/uploads/<guid>.<ext>", 
new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("width=2000;height=2000;format=jpg;mode=max"));
```

You can also call `Config.Current.Pipeline.GetFile` to get an IVirtualFile reference based on a path, if you just want the original data.